# How can I convert an html file into svelte, and keep the way the imports work?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm a new svelte developer and have written a simple code for a graph, but I cannot use it in a +page.svelte file only because it doesn't allow me to have multiple `<script>` tags (component can only have one instance-level `<script>` element). I already know I can only have one script tag at the top, and put all of my imports and code in there, but I NEED to have some code at the top, some imports at the bottom AND the middle, and some code at the very bottom. can you please help me how I can do this? here's my index.html file:

```html
<head>
    <!-- Required Meta Tags Always Come First -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Title -->
    <title>Alternative Dashboard | Front - Admin &amp; Dashboard Template</title>

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <!--    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico">-->

    <!-- Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css">-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/jsvectormap/dist/css/jsvectormap.min.css">-->

    <!-- CSS Front Template -->

    <link rel="preload" href="./src/css/theme.min.css" data-hs-appearance="default" as="style">
    <!--    <link rel="preload" href="./src/css/theme-dark.min.css" data-hs-appearance="dark" as="style">-->

    <style data-hs-appearance-onload-styles>
        *
        {
            transition: unset !important;
        }

        body
        {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        //some very necessary code in here, about 200 lines
    </script>
</head>

<!-- an import that MUST be in here -->
<script src="./src/js/hs.theme-appearance.js"></script>

<!--<script src="./src/hs-navbar-vertical-aside/dist/hs-navbar-vertical-aside-mini-cache.js"></script>-->



<!-- Content -->
<div class="content container-fluid">
    <!-- Card -->
    <div class="card mb-3 mb-lg-5">
        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="card-header card-header-content-sm-between">
            <h4 class="card-header-title mb-2 mb-sm-0">Recent projects</h4>

            <!-- Nav -->
            <ul class="nav nav-segment nav-fill" id="projectsTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" data-bs-toggle="chart" data-datasets="0" data-trigger="click" data-action="toggle">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="javascript:" data-bs-toggle="tab">This week</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" data-bs-toggle="chart" data-datasets="1" data-trigger="click" data-action="toggle">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:" data-bs-toggle="tab">Last week</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- End Nav -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Header -->

        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row align-items-sm-center mb-4">
                <div class="col-sm mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <span class="h1 mb-0">$7,431.14 USD</span>

                        <span class="text-success ms-2">
              <i class="bi-graph-up"></i> 25.3%
            </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Col -->

                <div class="col-sm-auto">
                    <!-- Legend Indicators -->
                    <div class="row fs-6">
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <span class="legend-indicator bg-primary"></span> Income
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <span class="legend-indicator bg-info"></span> Expenses
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Legend Indicators -->
                </div>
                <!-- End Col -->
            </div>
            <!-- End Row -->

            <!-- Bar Chart -->
            <div class="chartjs-custom" style="height: 18rem;">
                <canvas id="updatingLineChart">
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <!-- End Bar Chart -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Body -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Card -->
</div>
<!-- End Content -->



<!--more imports here-->
<!-- JS Global Compulsory  -->
<script src="./src/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./src/jquery-migrate/dist/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script src="./src/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->
<script src="./src/hs-navbar-vertical-aside/dist/hs-navbar-vertical-aside.min.js"></script>
<script src="./src/hs-form-search/dist/hs-form-search.min.js"></script>

<script src="./src/hs-nav-scroller/dist/hs-nav-scroller.min.js"></script>
<script src="./src/chart.js/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="./src/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="./src/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!--<script src="./src/jsvectormap/dist/js/jsvectormap.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="./src/jsvectormap/dist/maps/world.js"></script>-->

<!-- JS Front -->
<script src="./src/js/theme.min.js"></script>
<script src="./src/js/hs.theme-appearance-charts.js"></script>

<!-- JS Plugins Init. -->
<script>
    // and a lot of code in here, almost 100 lines
</script>

<!-- End Style Switcher JS -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Tags can be added to the `<head>` via [`<svelte:head>`](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#svelte-head).

If you need scripts elsewhere, you can wrap them in e.g. a `<div>`, so they no longer are at the top level. (These scripts will not be compiled like the component script, so Svelte specific features will *not* work.)